# Hollow fonts on android

Tags: fonts, typography, android

I use the typeface "Lobster_1.0_.otf" in my Android application, but the problem is, that some of the letters appear "hollow", with a black&white outline. You can see the problem on the following image:

[image]

Another typeface (CasLonItalic.ttf) had similar problem: only the character "l" was hollow. So I think there is something with the typefaces, but I don't know what.

I'm a basic user of TypeLight 3 (added Hungarian glyphs to Lobster), so I can make basic modifications if needed.

Comment: You say you added Hungarian glyphs to Lobster.  Are you able to reproduce this at all with an unmodified version of Lobster?  Have you ruled out that this could have been caused by modifications you made?  Just checking.

Comment: Yes, to all questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but it looks to me like you've taken a regular weight font and used a faux bold (that is, a software-generated bold version of the characters). If that's the case, then the problem lies in how the "bold" is being created rather than in the font itself.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the font has overlapping contours (left over from an auto-generated bold/outline operation) - that aren't visible on most font renderers because they all go in the same direction, but show up on other renderers that use a different algorithm?

For what it's worth, the filename (Lobster_1.0_.otf) strongly suggests you're using a much older version of that font.  [The latest according to the website is 1.4 which can be downloaded from here](http://www.impallari.com/lobster/) and supposedly is much improved.